# Why foundation buttons are build with <a href>?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Is there any reason to use `<a href>` instead of `<button>` to display a button using foundation ?

It seems to work properly using `<button>`, but docs mention `<a href>` (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html). What are the consequence if I use `<button>` instead of `<a href>` ?

Comment: Please tell me why you downvote this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Tricks answers this well here: http://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

`<button>` is a form element and as such can't go to a link, but it can fire a form's action, for example.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be progressive enhancement. If (for whatever reason) Foundation fails to load on a user's device, an anchor tag with a link will still function as a link, while a button will not. This will allow the user to still use the website, which is an advantage :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. It may be a reason, i didn't thought about it.

Comment: Also Hyperlinks allow users to open the target in a new tab.

Comment: @modiX I have presumed <a href=""></a> without any link, like in foundation docs.